# What is the coefficient of THE X in this record?

Tags: functions

What is the coefficient of the x in this record ? Explanation please.

$f(x) = (3x+2)^7(x-1)^7$

> A. -1307
>
> B. -448
>
> C. 348
>
> D. 1207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(3x+2)(x-1)=-2-x+3x^2$ and $(-2-x+3x^2)^7=(-2)^7+7\cdot (-2)^6\cdot(-x)+(\ldots)\cdot x^2$.